# Raspberry Pi 4 Undervoltage warning even with official AC adapter

Tags: pi-4, power-supply, voltage

My Pi 4 is relatively new and I previously used a 5V 3A tablet charger from an old Huawei device to power it without issue.

Recently, a lightning  bolt started appearing at the top right of the screen, so thinking there was a PS issue, I decided to buy a new generic 3A AC adapter.

Well, the lightning bolt was still there, so I said screw it and bought the official Pi4 3A charger.  Low and behold, the lightning bolt is still there!

So I decided to do a reflash of the OS (RetroPie).  Still there after a clean install.

Do I just have a defective Pi 4 or am I missing something somewhere in the settings?  The Pi setup is barebones... has nothing connected to it except the HDMI display.  Nothing on the GPIO pins.

Would appreciate any insights or assistance.

Comment: I would expect the official supply with attached cable to work. Many (most) USB cables are too thin and cause voltage drop. `vcgencmd get_throttled` will show if there is an issue (normally 0).

Comment: It is possible RetroPie does not provide proper firmware support. If you can try with Raspberry Pi OS

Comment: Perhaps the socket you connect the PS to is worn and oxidized or dirty.